# Print whole DataGridView on Crystal Report in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have a DataGridView populated manually through code using index numbers of Rows and Columns (No Dataset or DataSource)

e.g:

```
 dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "ABC";
 dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "XYZ";
```

Now I want this whole GridView to be printed on Crystal Report. How do I provide dataSource to Crystal Report or simply how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by exporting the data of datagridview into xml. And from that, you can use it as datasource for your crystal reports.

```
private void Transfer()
{
 DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);
 dSet.Tables.Add(dT);
 try
     {
     dSet.AcceptChanges();
     dSet.WriteXml(@"C:\MyData.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
      }
 catch (FileLoadException) { }

 ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();
        string filePath = @"C:\CrystalReportData.rpt";
        cr.Load(filePath);
        cr.SetDataSource(dSet);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
}
```